# gwt-phonegap and mgwt

Tags: cordova, mgwt

looking into mobile app development and trying to understand the technologies out there. Where do these two things fit, mgwt and gwt-phonegap, are they competing technologies/frameworks or do they compliment each other.  Where do they fit in in the development cycle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mgwt provides mobile widgets for GWT, while gwt-phonegap provides integration for phonegap.

If you want to build a webpage you can just use mgwt. If you want to build an application that you can deploy into the apple app store or google play you will need gwt-phonegap & phonegap as well.

If you want a good overview you might want to watch one of my talk about mgwt on youtube: http://youtu.be/0V0CdhMFiao